# [UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I have read several answers on this question but can't seem to find one that applies to my code.  When I assign the "text" member of "myLabel" (below) I get: "[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...."  The program compiles OK but then crashes when the assignment statement is encountered.

However I am able to assign and even print out the backgroundColor of the same object.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

//********
     import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//*********  Button 1 *********//


@IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!


@IBAction func btn1(sender: AnyObject) {

    nextColorFor1++
    makeColor (self.lbl1, nextColor: nextColor1)

}

//****  Button 2  **********//


@IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!

@IBAction func btn2(sender: AnyObject) {

    nextColorFor2++
    makeColor (self.lbl2, nextColor: nextColorFor2)

}
```

//***************************//

```
func makeColor (myLabel:UILabel, nextColor:Int)
{
    switch nextColor
    {
    case 0: myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
    case 1: myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
    case 2: myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    case 3: myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.4, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
    case 4: myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    default: print("end of colors")
    }

    print(myLabel.backgroundColor)
    myLabel.text = "4"  <<< --- This is where the crask occurs
}


override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

}
```

Comment: One more thing --- both the button and label are wired together.

Comment: To avoid confusion don't use the same name for instance and local variables (`myLabel`).

Comment: What do you mean with both the button and label being wired together?

Comment: Is there any reason to downvote my answer? I tried and I put here.

Comment: Sorry folks.  I think that when I tried to simplify the example, I lost some of the explanation of what I am trying to do and subsequently caused confusion in some of your responses.  Sorry about that.  I have modified the code to show that I have to send multiple possibilities of the label to the function.  Also, each object is pointed to by a label and a button. (p.s. user3182143 - it wasn't me who downvoted your answer)

Comment: the reason you can set the background color is both uilabel and uibutton (indirectly from uiresponder )inherit from uiview. so the background color is common in both.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have connected the `UIButton`(which is on your storyboard or xib) as as `UILabel` in the code, and you are trying to treat it as label. Make sure to replace the button on the IB to label, and it will work.

Comment: Xocode does not allow to connect mis-matched type as outlet. Attempting to connect a unbutton to uilabel is not allowed by xocde.I guess he has connected the outlet right but after that changed the type of uibutton to uilable in the code.

Comment: I assume then that I would not be able to do what I am seeking and will find another route.  Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: CNE did you try my below answer?.If it is helpful for you, I will be so happy.

Comment: Your solution would work if there was no need to pass the label as a parameter to the makeColor function.  However, I need to pass it since processing in the function is determined by which button/label was selected.  Please see the modified code that I posted with the complete code so it is evident what I am trying to do.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the local variable

```
func makeColor()
{
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)

    print(myLabel.backgroundColor)
    myLabel.text = "4"
}

@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   makeColor ()
}
```

Now If you want  to set the title for button

```
@IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
    myButton.titleLabel?.text = "4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to ease the bug in case the origin (xib || storyboard) is unknown

```
extension UIButton
{
    func setText(_ text: String) {
        assertionFailure("crashlytics reported Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xyyy objc_exception_throw        keyboard_arrow_down")
        titleLabel?.text = text
    }
}
```